# What themes does GTK+ provide by default?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I want to change the default GTK theme for Windows. I know how to do that:
by modifying the `settings.ini` file,
or like this:

```cpp
settings = gtk_settings_get_default();
gtk_settings_set_string_property(settings, "gtk-theme-name", "ThemeName", NULL);
```

the problem is the documentation does not provide a list of possible values to use in place of `ThemeName`, what values does that argument accept?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are talking about doing this on Microsoft Windows, right? I would answer the question but I don't know how GTK+ for Windows is set up or distributed... Also, do you mean defining a theme that your application **will** use, or providing a drop-down list of themes for the user to choose from?

Comment: for example what are the values accepted by this property : "gtk-theme-name"

Comment: The reason I asked the specific questions I did is that themes are installed by the user. You *can* get a list of installed themes, but I don't know how to do this on Microsoft Windows (as I don't know what the folders used on that system are). There *are* predefined themes in GTK+ 3, but I don't know which of those are provided on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the question is not really answerable: there can be as many themes as you install in a directory reachable by GTK+ itself. you cannot enumerate them programmatically, since it's a user (or at least an application developer) setting, and you can ship as many themes as you like in your own application.

there are various themes built in within GTK+, depending on the platform.

available on every platform, you have:

- `Raleigh`
- `Adwaita` (starting from GTK+ 3.14)
- `HighConstrast` (starting from GTK+ 3.16)

on Windows you also have the `win32` theme available. the default theme, starting from GTK+ 3.14, is `Adwaita`.